# trying to access remote database using php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i am trying to access remote database using PHP.
remote database is MySQL. Below is the screen shot of the error i am getting.can any one help me.Thanks in advance.

following are perfectly alright i have checked:-

1. Database name
2. port number
3. IP address
4. username and password

here is the database connectivity code

```
<?php

class Database {
/*  
    public  $dbhost = "mysql:dbname=a_t;host=localhost:3306";
    $dbhost = "mysql:host=10.75.225.171;port=3306;dbname=apt";
    public  $dbuser = "root";
    public  $dbpass = "root";
    public  $dbname = "a_t";
    public  $connection;
    public  $selectdb;
    public  $isConnected;
    public  $dbh;

    */

    public  $dbhost = "mysql:dbname=25thcraft;host=52.xx.xx.xxx;port=3306";

    public  $dbuser = "tribhuvan";
    public  $dbpass = "123456";
    public  $dbname = "25thcraft";
    public  $connection;
    public  $selectdb;
    public  $isConnected;
    public  $dbh;

    //$user = 'dbuser';
    //$password = 'dbpass';

    public function Connection()
    {
        try
        {   
             $this->dbh = new PDO($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
            // echo "true";
                return  $this->dbh;
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        { 
                $this->isConnected = false;
                throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function Disconnect()
    {
        $this->datab = null;
        $this->isConnected = false;
    }
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: You might find that the webhost has the database firewalled in such a way as to only accept connections from a particular host ( this is very common ) and not from any remote host such as your PC at home. You could create a proxy on your live site to which you connect perhaps

Answer (score 0):

If you want make a connection to a remote connection, the host must be configured to accept these connections. Which are disables by default. The best you can contact the host to look into this.

Comment: can u please explain where exactly we have to change the defult settings

Comment: If you use DirectAdmin http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=308.
If you use your own server you can use a tutorial like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql

Comment: i am new to remote database connectivity can u please explain in detail

Comment: The first question is, where is your mysql database, on your own server or on a remote hoster location

Comment: database is in ec2 free tier. I have managed to install xampp in xampp phpmyadmin is my database

Comment: Can you create a SSH connetion to the Linux?

Comment: mine is windows server

Comment: Try following this tutorial http://www.programcreek.com/2009/09/how-to-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-server-on-windows/

Comment: Then just `telnet 52.xx.xx.xxx 3306` from the application server to confirm the DB/firewall is configured to accept such connections.